# SSHD Password Feedback (Show Asterisks for Characters)

Tags: sshd, centos

Is it possible to have SSHD show asterisks for the password characters much like `pwfeedback` does for sudo?  I am using CentOS 6.5.

For example: [image: if I type something here, show *****]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override what tool is used to ask for the passwords/passphrases via the environment variable `$SSH_ASKPASS`.

```
$ echo $SSH_ASKPASS
/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
```

*excerpt - [Password Reading and Handling](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/crypto/passwd_input.txt)*

> Password Reading Programs.
>
> Why re-invent the wheel. There are lots of programs that have already been
>   written for getting password from users, and which then pipe the result to
>   stdout, ready to feed into the program that needs it, or to be buffered in
>   a variable.
>
> Examples include...
>
> ```
>   /usr/libexec/openssh/x11-ssh-askpass
>   /usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass
>   /usr/bin/ssh-askpass
>   /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
>   /usr/lib/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
>   zenity --title=Program --entry --text=Password: --hide-text
>   Xdialog --title Program --stdout --password --inputbox "Password:" 0x0
>   { echo "SETDESC password:"; echo "GETPIN"; } | pinentry | sed -n 's/^D //p'
> ```
>
> And probably many many others that essentially does exactly what the above
>   script is trying to do.  I have often written encrypting and mounting scripts
>   that search to find at least one of these programs to use for user password
>   input.

#### References

- [Entering password in Terminal gives no visual feedback](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/194472)
- [Lack of visual feedback on password entry](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/52914)

Answer (score 0):

Nice copy and paste from my document -- good to know it gets some use :-)

I have problems with just about all the password entry programs such as those I listed, and posted by slm.They were generally designed for a specific program to use, typically SSH, and little or no options.  And yes I know that is what the original poster wants.

But there are many situations where you want a program to read a password for other purposes (encryption, mounts, restricted access), and so far every program I have looked at has problems being re-purposed.

For example:

No options:  (almost all ssh-askpass programs - except x11-ssh-askpass)

No control of window title  (pinentry, x11-ssh-askpass)

Or just plain looks bulky and horrible (Xdialog)

Lack of control over keyboard focus or keyboard grabs (they are different!)

Also when encrypting files, you actually want to have the user type the password twice (to make sure it is right), and compare them (either by the askpass program or left to the caller). At this time NO X window program seems to allow this type double password entry. :-(

My current choice is 'zenity' and 'x11-ssh-askpass'  but as it stands most of the above programs could really use more and better options!